# $a^2 + b^2 +c^2 +d^2 = 8r^2$ for orthodiagonal quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

$\square ABCD$ orthodiagonal quadrilateral, $r$ is circumradius.
Prove, that $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 = 8r^2$.

I proved by Pythagoras, that $a^2+c^2 =b^2+d^2$, but don`t know how to proceed from here and if my approach is good or not.

Comment: You can find a proof here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthodiagonal_quadrilateral#Properties_of_orthodiagonal_quadrilaterals_that_are_also_cyclic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wiki CyclicQuad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral)

You are implying a cyclic quadrilateral in order to have a single $r.$

Follow equations for $D,R$  under heading *circum-radius and area*.

Circum-diameter $d=2r$ is expressed in terms of divided segments of orthodiagonal quadrilateral.

$$d^2= p_1^2+p_2^2+q_1^2+q_2^2,$$

$$ d= \sqrt{a^2+c^2} =\sqrt{b^2+d^2}  ,\, $$

and result follows